# How would you personify fear?

Tags: fiction

I need to represent fear in a human form...I am looking for ideas:)

Comment: Sorry, but as written this is a pretty broad "what should I write?" question.  Is there a more-specific aspect of the problem that you're having trouble with?  What approaches have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

SE isn't an idea genertor.

**Writers often use the "Shadow archetype" from Campbell and Jung's writings. It represents fear of something that the hero is afraid of become,** just as Luke Skywalker was afraid of becoming somebody like his father.

If you want ideas for "how" personify that fear, go take a look into the greek mythology, read about phobos and other myths about fear. Horror stories are a great place to take a look as well, because the monsters of these kind of stories represents a **specific kind of fear, not fear as a whole**. **Because everybody has different fears, just as they have different desires.**